# Android - How to determine if external speaker is connected

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I want to play sound in an app only if it is NOT played through the phone's built in speaker. To do this, I assume I need to find out if there is an external speaker connected (wired speaker, bluetooth headset, wired headset, etc).

I see that `AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()` is deprecated but still works, however this only shows that a wired headset is plugged in. Is there a similar option for bluetooth? Will that cover all the possible audio options?

Conversely, if there is a way to tell that sound WILL be routed through the built in speaker, that would probably work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean isWiredHeadsetConnected() {    
        AudioManager mAudioMgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(mAudioMgr.isWiredHeadsetOn()){

                 mAudioMgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
                 mAudioMgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                 mAudioMgr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SpeakerPhone On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
}
```

There's an intent to detect whether or not one is being plugged or unplugged: `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`. So, you must add it.

```
public static boolean isBluetoothHeadsetConnected() {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
            && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED;
}
```

Bluetooth permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must extend the `OnAudioFocusChangeListener`class. In it's `onAudioFocusChange` function, you will be notified of each and every event related to audio.

Changes in the state of an external speaker are monitored with the `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`constant (it is provided to you as an `onAudioFocusChange` parameter ).

Comment: This only will show focus change. I want to check that an external speaker is connected prior to playing sound. Also, `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is only for monitoring wired headsets, as far as I can tell in the documentation.